# I've taken a screenshot, how do I edit it?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, screen-capture

I'm used to taking screenshots in Windows and then editing them before posting them (with MSPaint)

How can I edit a simple image quickly on OSX?

I took a picture of a P.O. and I want to remove any PII information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a default application named `Preview` in OS-X for editing images.

If you created any screen shots, just open that screenshot image in `Preview` application and you can see the edit toolbar to edit the image.

[image]

Comment: Beware: I annotated a PNG of a screenshot without saving it explicitly, but Preview decided to save the annotations without being asked.  I don't know whether there's a setting to counteract that behaviour, but it was certainly a surprise.  Also, once saved, the annotation is just a part of the image — it is no longer editable.  Make sure you work on a copy of an image before annotating the first time (it might be a quirk on my machine).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs you could use one of these free tools:

- Apple's Preview (Built-in with OSX)
- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)
- [Sketchbook Express](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/sketchbook-express/id404243625?mt=12)

If you want something more advanced you could try

- [Adobe's Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html)
- [Pixelmator](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12)

Comment: I also have used "Seashore". Also free.  I find Gimp to be very hard to use and un-Mac-like.

Comment: It appears that as of 2017-01-10, Sketchbook Express is no longer available (at least, from a Mac).

Answer (score 3):

I found another application named [**Skitch**](http://evernote.com/skitch/) for Mac to edit the screenshot. There are many features like [free hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to) (which is not available in the Preview app) are available in this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have either an Android device or iOS and need a really comprehensive efficient image editor; export or save the screen shots (any image) into you iPhoto/google drive or Dropbox etc and then give [Google SNAPSEED - (iOS Link)](https://itunes.apple.com/EN/app/snapseed/id439438619?mt=8%E2%80%8E)  a go!.

I have used Adobe CS (Photoshop) etc professionally for years to edit compile images but I find this app really useful and nifty is the best for quick on the fly adjustments for work or fun and is extremely versatile - It doesn't give an Instagram/ready-made one click template feel to your pictures (unless you choose that vibe). If you want to use built in apps then iPhoto should be really fine for basic editing.

With GIMP — unless you have used packages like Adobe CS before — you will have lots of homework to do but it's fun free and does everything that Photoshop does in pretty much the same way or simpler once you work your way around it!

[image: Some examples of pictures I have edited with the app and taken on iPad or DSLR][image: EG2][image: EG3]Sorry I don't have before and after for all or in order[image: After]

[image: Before]

Comment: It appears that as of 2017-01-10, Snapseed is not available from iTunes (at least, not from a Mac).